# What problem does Julia solve for data science?

Tags: julia, data-science

I am not able to find any definitive answer to what problem Julia solves compared to the two languages, I was told are most commonly used in working with data (data science), R and Python.

I am not asking for any opinions. Please support replies with factual information (sad I need to add this but it seems some people think this topic is opinion based).

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of them, but I just googled this - so maybe it will help :-)
https://www.codementor.io/@evalparse/julia-vs-r-vs-python-simple-optimization-gnqi4njro

Comment: Check this :https://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/when-do-micro-optimizations-matter-in-scientific-computing/

Comment: @longemen3000 thanks that link looks promising. I'll read it soon as I got some time as I am interested in the content it links to as well.

Comment: This would be much better suited to http://discourse.julialang.org/ where there are less restriction on the format. I would expect to see this closed on stackoverflow shortly.

Comment: @LyndonWhite doubt it. Similar topics are still active. This is not a topic asking for an opinion but has its focus on factual information. I also doubt any real objectivity in the answerd if I was to place this question on a Julia forum...

Comment: There's a lot of interesting stuff at stochasticlifestyle.com. I think these post are even more relevant to the OP: https://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/why-numba-and-cython-are-not-substitutes-for-julia/ and https://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/like-julia-scales-productive-insights-julia-developer/

Answer (score 3):

The Julia Programming Language solves the same problems as R and Python. However, it can solve them extremely faster than those mentioned above, as it runs over C code and uses a JIT compiler. See the [Julia Benchmark](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/). This and other advantages that can be found at the [language site](https://julialang.org/), it's Twitter profiles: [Julia Computing](https://twitter.com/JuliaComputing) and [Julia Language](https://twitter.com/JuliaLanguage).

Comment: It does not run much C code, nor does nit always run faster than C code, so I'm not sure what you mean with "it runs over C code"?

Comment: I would say that is can make programmers write fast code faster :-) No, seriously.. one go to Julia because of the run time performance, but then it remains because writing the code is much more elegant.. do you prefer `using LinearAlgebra
a = [4,1]
b = [2,3]
normC = dot(a,b)/norm(b)
c = (dot(a,b)/norm(b)^2) * b` or `import numpy as np
a = np.array([4,1])
b = np.array([2,3])
normC = np.dot(a,b)/np.linalg.norm(b)
c = (np.dot(a,b)/np.linalg.norm(b)**2) * b` ??